# CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL not open at local host

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

when I am starting wso2server.sh, CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL not open at local host

Comment: Provide the URL here which you accessed. We hope you are using WSO2 ESB 4.9.0.

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan, instead of https://localhost:9443/carbon/, it started on  https://xxx.xx.0.1:9443/carbon/ and when I hit this url, browser says, Your connection is not secure

Comment: Check your network interfaces and their IP addresses. Have you run docker in your machine? If so, docker will create a internal IP address for it's network interface.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the question completely but what is the URL you are trying to hit? To open the carbon UI, you have to hit https://ipaddress:9443/carbon

If you want any Admin Services to be available, go to /repository/conf/carbon.xml and make HideAdminServiceWSDLs tag as false.

Comment: i want to run it on localhost ip address, but instead of localhost it's started on different ip address

Comment: What is the version you are using? What is the url you are trying to hit?

Comment: I am using WSO2 ESB 4.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the {CARBON_HOME}/repository/conf/carbon.xml in the  and  you set another IP diferent to localhost